# $3(2x^2+x-2)^2=8x^2+4x-9$

Tags: quadratics

I should solve the following biquadratic equation with changing of variables (e.g., $x^2=z$). I do not see how to do it, and I think the answer in my book does not cover all solutions: $1$ and $-\dfrac{3}{2}$.

$3(2x^2+x-2)^2=8x^2+4x-9$

Comment: Let $t=2x^2+x$ and perform a substitution on both sides.  Then show us your solution.

Comment: or what about $2x^2+x-2$?

Comment: I don't know how to factor $8x^2+4x-9$.

Comment: can you relate $8x^2+4x-9$ to $2x+x$?

Comment: Ignore the $-9$.

Comment: How can I substitute the right side of the equation with $2x^2+x$ or $2x^2+x-2$?

Comment: what is the relationship between $8x^2+4x$ and $2x^2+x$?

Comment: $8x^2+4x=4(2x^2+x)$.

Comment: Thank you. So I guess the other two solutions that WolframAlpha suggests are complex? Is that right?

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/YivbNRo.png

Comment: no, they're somewhat complicated (not pretty), but not complex (they are real)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Partial answer.** Observe $8x^2+4x-9=4(2x^2+x)-9.$ Now, we can let $y:=2x^2+x$ which gives $$3(y-2)^2=4y-9.$$ This then is equivalent to $$3y^2-12y+12=4y-9\Rightarrow3y^2-16y+21=0\Rightarrow(3y-7)(y-3)=0\Rightarrow y=7/3,\quad y=3.$$

Now we can undo the substitutions and we should get the desired answers.

Comment: Thank you! Why did you say 'partial answer'?

Comment: No worries! I guess technically it's not a full answer. Still have to do the $2x^2+x=7/3$ and $2x^2+x=3$ parts.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Left minus right-hand side can factorized into
$$(x-1) (2 x+3) \left(6 x^2+3
   x-7\right)=0$$